# save file path to mysql by java

Tags: java, mysql

I have read all solution but now i haven't know how to save a file path to mysql by java jdbc.
Here is my code :

```
enter  try{
        String url= "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con= DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
        System.out.println("ket noi thanh cong");
        s = con.createStatement( );

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        fileName = f.getAbsolutePath().toString();

        String input = "INSERT INTO imagesrc ( image_src ) VALUES (?);";
        PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(input);
        p.setString(1, fileName);

        System.out.println(p.toString());
        p.executeQuery();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("error");
    } here
```

but is doesn't run and error ?
when I print the SQL code by :

```
System.out.println(p.toString());
```

copy and paste that to mysql is was run and no error ?
please help me,thank you

thank you salah anh this is the solution for this:

```
String url= "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con= DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
    System.out.println("ket noi thanh cong");
    s = con.createStatement( );

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    fileName = f.getAbsolutePath();

    String input = "INSERT INTO imagesrc ( image_src ) VALUES (?)";
     PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(input);
     p.setString(1, fileName);
     // s.executeUpdate(input);
     p.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: post the error message

Comment: the error is: 
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Comment: Your getAbsolutePath() method it self returns  a string why are you calling toString on it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the executeUpdate() method to execute the INSERT statement, while you'll need to use the executeQuery() method to execute the SELECT statement. This is due to the requirements imposed by the JDBC specification on their usages:

From the Java API documentation for [Statement.executeQuery()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29):

> Executes the given SQL statement, which returns a single ResultSet
>   object.
>
> Parameters:
>
> sql - an SQL statement to be sent to the database, typically a **static SQL SELECT statement**

and from the Java API documentation for [Statement.executeUpdate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454627/can-not-issue-data-manipulation-statements-with-executequery/6454908#6454908):

> Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.
>
> Parameters:
>
> sql - an **SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement**, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or **an SQL statement that returns nothing**, such as a DDL statement.

For more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454627/can-not-issue-data-manipulation-statements-with-executequery/6454908#6454908)